Local microk8s on raspberry pi with pending letsencrypt
I am trying to issue a letsencrypt certificate to my domain on my local raspberry single node cluster running ArgoCD. It keeps stall on pending with the message:
waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: did not get expected response when querying endpoint, expected "<TOKEN>" but got:

and if I do a
curl http://budgetapp.hagh.dk/.well-known/acme-challenge/<TOKEN>

I get an empty 200 response. No token provided
I am losing my mind. I have tried several solutions include deleting the challenge and order multiple times with the same result (just like Einstein said)
This is my ingress for my app
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: budgetapp-ingress
  namespace: budgetapp
  annotations:
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: 'true'
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-production"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: budgetapp.hagh.dk
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: budgetapp-budgetapp-backend
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - budgetapp.hagh.dk
      secretName: budgetapp.hagh.dk.tls

which I push to github repo and sync in argocd. The challenge and order are then created successfully but on pending
This is my ClusterIssuer config
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
 name: letsencrypt-production
spec:
 acme:
   email: mymail@gmail.com
   server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
   privateKeySecretRef:
     name: letsencrypt-production-issuer-account-key
   solvers:
   - selector: {}
     http01:
       ingress:
         class: nginx

Please let me know if any more info is needed. And any help where I might be missing something is really appreciated.

Forgot to write, that it is not running locally. It is connected to the internet and the domain points to my public IP and my router forwards the traffic to my raspberry pi.
I can access the app with "http" externally just fine
